# How to send cURL/API requests in C# with webRequest Class Multible Commands

Tags: c#, curl, webrequest

I need to send this so a Server:

```
curl https://api.placetel.de/api/getRouting.xml \
    -d 'api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    -d 'number=068111111XXX'
```

if i try:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.placetel.de/api/getRouting.xml");
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX number=0685123XXXXXX";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            listBox1.Items.Add(responseFromServer);
```

i get a login error - api not right becouse my programm sends the api + number= in "one line"

the question is how can i send it like in two commands`? i try with strings postData & postData1 aso - that doesn´t work

like:

```
string postData1 = "\nnumber=068567909000";
  byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData1);
```

Comment: what is `postData1`?

Comment: How about reading a few docs about what `-d` means http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html `If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ContentType` and separate each parameter with an ampersand:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var postData = "api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
postData += "&number=0685123XXXXXX";
```